pyenv - BUILD FAILED (OS X 14.4 using python-build 20180424)
MacOS Sonoma
pyenv install 3.9.9
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.9.9.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.9/Python-3.9.9.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.9.9...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use ncurses from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 14.4 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/gb/qw4m3z9x49n7d53pl5j_t_s40000gp/T/python-build.20240517153702.30044
Results logged to /var/folders/gb/qw4m3z9x49n7d53pl5j_t_s40000gp/T/python-build.20240517153702.30044.log

Last 10 log lines:
  File "/private/var/folders/gb/qw4m3z9x49n7d53pl5j_t_s40000gp/T/python-build.20240517153702.30044/Python-3.9.9/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 206, in _main
    return _bootstrap(
  File "/private/var/folders/gb/qw4m3z9x49n7d53pl5j_t_s40000gp/T/python-build.20240517153702.30044/Python-3.9.9/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 125, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/private/var/folders/gb/qw4m3z9x49n7d53pl5j_t_s40000gp/T/python-build.20240517153702.30044/Python-3.9.9/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 34, in _run_pip
    return subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", code], check=True).returncode
  File "/private/var/folders/gb/qw4m3z9x49n7d53pl5j_t_s40000gp/T/python-build.20240517153702.30044/Python-3.9.9/Lib/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/private/var/folders/gb/qw4m3z9x49n7d53pl5j_t_s40000gp/T/python-build.20240517153702.30044/Python-3.9.9/python.exe', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'/var/folders/gb/qw4m3z9x49n7d53pl5j_t_s40000gp/T/tmp8thxua6f/setuptools-58.1.0-py3-none-any.whl\', \'/var/folders/gb/qw4m3z9x49n7d53pl5j_t_s40000gp/T/tmp8thxua6f/pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'/var/folders/gb/qw4m3z9x49n7d53pl5j_t_s40000gp/T/tmp8thxua6f\', \'--root\', \'/\', \'--upgrade\', \'setuptools\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.
make: *** [install] Error 1

I tried installing pyenv in mac. My pyenev is installed from Homebrew
M1 Pro mac
